# Requesting assistance with embedded for loops in C++

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, while-loop, ascii

I am currently working on a project for a CS class and I have been tasked with printing out a ASCII model of a building. The objective of this project is to allow the user to input an integer and have that integer be the amount of "sections" the building has. Below I have broken down the example given to me into sections. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you to anyone taking the time to read this.

The pattern is as follows. Section x = ((x * 2) + 2) = amount of lines of code & "width" of building. (x = any integer value)

```
  |\/|
  |/\|                //section 0      ((section * 2) + 2)
  /--\                                   0 + 2 = 2


 |\::/|
 |:\/:|               //section 1      ((section * 2) + 2)
 |:/\:|                                  2 + 2 = 4
 |/::\|
 /----\


|\::::/|
|:\::/:|
|::\/::|              //section 2       ((section * 2) + 2)
|::/\::|                                  4 + 2 = 6
|:/::\:|
|/::::\|
/------\
```

I managed to figure out the pattern, but am having a really hard time with embedding several loops within one another. The best representation of this building I have so far is this.

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int size = 2;
int sizeAdj = (size * 2) + 2;
int leftMost = sizeAdj;


for(i = 0; i <= size; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < 1; j++){
            cout<<setw(leftMost + 1)<<"|";
            cout<<"\\";
            cout<<"/";
            cout<<"|";
            cout<<endl;
            for(j = 0; j < 1; j++){
                cout<<setw(leftMost + 1)<<"|";
                cout<<"/";
                cout<<"\\";
                cout<<"|";
     }
     leftMost = leftMost - 1;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

And this prints out the following.

```
  |\/|
  |/\|
 |\/|
 |/\|
|\/|
|/\|
```

Once more, thank you.

Comment: 1. The example does not seem correct: the height  & width are different. 2. You could use a square array filled with `:`, replace the borders and diagonals and finally print it row by row - no need for nested, confusing loops.

Comment: @TheFailurebyDesign To clarify for 1. I was not counting the bottom "layer" as I figured that would be an independent loop. As for 2. I am not sure how to go about doing that, could you please explain it further? Thank you for commenting!

Comment: @user4581301 I was able to print a box using two for loops and this was the "evolution" of the box. I am not sure how to rotate the "upper stage" and the "lower stage" in each segment without repeating them one after the other though. I think I might have to use setw() between the characters to modify the spacing but I do not want to even think about that yet. Thank you for commenting!

Comment: My apologies. I misread the sections as different test runs and didn't realize it was all one building converging as it rose.

Comment: @user4581301 No worries! :)

Comment: @user4581301 me neither, I thought section 0 up to 2 is the full picture :/

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I dont see the pattern in your code.

Start simpler. First dont worry about the space at the front:

```
|\/|
|/\|                //section 0      ((section * 2) + 2)
/--\                                   0 + 2 = 2


|\::/|
|:\/:|               //section 1      ((section * 2) + 2)
|:/\:|                                  2 + 2 = 4
|/::\|
/----\


|\::::/|
|:\::/:|
|::\/::|              //section 2       ((section * 2) + 2)
|::/\::|                                  4 + 2 = 6
|:/::\:|
|/::::\|
/------\
```

if you have that you just need to add `x` spaces in front.

Next, the symmetry is more obvious when we add a "fake" line:

```
\----/
|\::/|
|:\/:|               //section 1      ((section * 2) + 2)
|:/\:|                                  2 + 2 = 4
|/::\|
/----\
```

Now width and height are the same and we can use

```
int width(int x) { return (x*2)+2; }
```

Write a function that returns the right character for a given position

```
char get_simple_pattern(int x,int row,int col) {
     if (row == col) return '\\';
     // ...
     return ':';
}
```

Use two loops to print it

```
void print_simple_pattern(int x) {
   for (int row=0; row < width(x); ++row) {
       for (int col=0; col < width(x); ++col) {
           std::cout << get_simple_pattern(x,row,col);
       }
       std::cout << "\n";
   }
}
```

Once you have this correct you have to

- add `x` spaces in front of each row: `std::cout << std::string(x,' ');`
- skip the first row
- add a loop over `x`

Answer (score 1):

> but am having a really hard time with embedding several loops within one another.

From the looks of it, you are having a hard time writing effective loops and just didn't notice until you tried nesting them. Take a look at your loops using `j` as the loop control variable:

> ```
> for(j = 0; j < 1; j++)
> ```

Technically, this is a looping statement. However, it sets `j` to `0`, runs the loop **once**, then increments `j` to `1` and exits the loop. It's hard to consider this a real loop when there is always just one iteration. You'd have less busywork for the computer if you skipped the `for` statement and just set `j = 0`.

Still, there is a problem with the way you have loops nested. Your looping structures (ignoring the other statements in the loop bodies) is the following.

> ```
> for(i = 0; i <= size; i++){
>     for(j = 0; j < 1; j++){
>         for(j = 0; j < 1; j++){
> ```

Notice that the middle and innermost loops both use `j`? That's a disaster waiting to happen. Don't have a nested loop mess with the loop control variable of a containing loop.

---

Even better, try to avoid nesting loops. Think about what you want to happen with each iteration of a loop, then delegate that functionality to a different function. For example, your outermost loop might look like:

```
for(i = 0; i <= size; i++)
    printSection(i, size);
```

Then you could write a `printSection` function to handle each section of the building. This would be the intent of your middle loop, right? (If not, adjust the details to match your intent. The point is to avoid jumbling a lot of steps into one chunk of code.) You could easily test this function by itself. Have your main function, for example, call `printSection(1,2);` instead of using a loop, and make sure the output matches what's in your problem description. Repeat for `printSection(2,2);` and as many other examples as you need to be confident that this function works as intended.

```
// Print section number `section` for a building with `size` sections.
void printSection(int section, int size)
{
    for(int i = 0; i <= section; i++) {
        // Handle the indent here, since it is the same throughout the section.
        cout << setw(size - section) << ' ';
        // Delegate the floor details to another function.
        printFloor(i, section);
        // End the line. Alternatively, this could be delegated to printFloor.
        cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

You might notice that I used `i` in both loops. Didn't I say that's a problem? It would be if the loops were directly nested. However, they are in separate functions, so no problem.

Next, you would write the `printFloor` function. I would 
start simple; have `printFloor(int floor, int section)` initially just write a pipe character (`'|'`), followed by `2*section + 2` colons, followed by another pipe character. Once you get that working, you can worry about the X through the building. Start small, divide-and-conquer, and make sure each piece works before joining things together.

Answer (score 0):

I did this in C for fun.... for whatever its worth:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void print_section(int n, int z)
{
    char dots[2*n+1];
    memset(dots,':',2*n+1);
    dots[2*n+1]=0;
    for(int r=0;r<n+1;++r)
    {
        printf("%*.s|%.*s\\%.*s/%.*s|\n",z-n,"",r,dots,2*(n-r),dots,r,dots);
    }

    for(int r=n;r>=0;--r)
    {
        printf("%*.s|%.*s/%.*s\\%.*s|\n",z-n,"",r,dots,2*(n-r),dots,r,dots);
    }
    memset(dots,'-',2*(n+1));
    printf("%*.s/%.*s\\\n",z-n,"",2*(n+1),dots);
}

int main(void) {
    int sections;
    printf("Please enter number of sections: \n");
    scanf("%d", &sections);

    for(int s=0; s<sections; ++s)
    {
        print_section(s, sections);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

### Output

*for 5 sections*

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 4276KB
Please enter number of sections:  5
     |\/|
     |/\|
     /--\
    |\::/|
    |:\/:|
    |:/\:|
    |/::\|
    /----\
   |\::::/|
   |:\::/:|
   |::\/::|
   |::/\::|
   |:/::\:|
   |/::::\|
   /------\
  |\::::::/|
  |:\::::/:|
  |::\::/::|
  |:::\/:::|
  |:::/\:::|
  |::/::\::|
  |:/::::\:|
  |/::::::\|
  /--------\
 |\::::::::/|
 |:\::::::/:|
 |::\::::/::|
 |:::\::/:::|
 |::::\/::::|
 |::::/\::::|
 |:::/::\:::|
 |::/::::\::|
 |:/::::::\:|
 |/::::::::\|
 /----------\
```

Comment: This actually helps tremendously! I needed to see the "flow" of things and while I've never programmed in C I think I get the idea of whats happening. I'm going back into the cave of productivity (my office) to try some new things, thank you for responding!

Comment: If you wanted C, why'd you tag [C++]?

Comment: I did not want C, but its what I was provided with and Im still grateful for the response. C & C++ are similar enough where I have a decent understanding even though I gotta look some things up.

Comment: I spoke too soon, I tried to interpret what you wrote but I came up short. I do not understand significant portions of the program. If it is not too much trouble, could you please explain it a little further or describe it in C++. Thank you.

Comment: Code-only answers tend to be not useful in the long run, often not in the short run either.

Comment: @GeorgiN One strategy you can use here is to pick one of the problem areas, preferably one that will help you understand other portions, and ask a new question about it. Also good is to use a debugger to step through the code to watch what it does. If you have trouble with how it does it, the C functions used here are insanely well documented (and they should be after nearly 50 years). Where that leaves questions, ask a Question.

Comment: @user4581301 Thats what I ended up going, I just started trying to understand it by // certain lines of code to see what effect they have on the program. Thank you for the advice! I am relatively new to programming and every bit of support helps.